Utimaco HSM integration with java application
i am facing challangs while integrating my application with utimaco HSM.
i have downloaded the Utimaco simulator and along with that i am getting java code as well.
here i am able to connect with HSM. once installed the simulator.
With the help of crypto server simulator i am able to set the password to my admin user and able to connect.
with the help of code snippet i am able to store some keys in the hsm.
follwing is the sample code.
String device = "3001@127.0.0.1";
            cxi = new CryptoServerCXI(device, 3000);
            cxi.logon("CXI_HMAC", "", "*******".getBytes());
            String group = "test1";
            CryptoServerCXI.KeyAttributes attr = new CryptoServerCXI.KeyAttributes();
            attr.setAlgo(CryptoServerCXI.KEY_ALGO_AES);
            attr.setSize(256);
            attr.setName("CXI_AES_IMP_KEY");
            attr.setGroup(group);
    
            final byte[] aesKeyBytes = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(hsmKeyDTO.getMasterKey().getBytes());

            System.out.println("aesKey: --------" + aesKeyBytes);

            CryptoServerCXI.KeyComponents comp = new CryptoServerCXI.KeyComponents(aesKeyBytes);

and try to get the keys with the following code.
String device = "3001@127.0.0.1";
        cxi = new CryptoServerCXI(device, 3000);
        cxi.logon("CXI_HMAC", "", "***********".getBytes());

        String group = "test1";
        CryptoServerCXI.KeyAttributes attr = new CryptoServerCXI.KeyAttributes();
        attr.setAlgo(CryptoServerCXI.KEY_ALGO_AES);
        attr.setSize(256);
        attr.setName("CXI_AES_IMP_KEY");
        attr.setGroup(group);

        CryptoServerCXI.Key aesKey = cxi.findKey(attr);
        
          attr = new CryptoServerCXI.KeyAttributes();
          attr.setGroup(group);
    

          attr.setName("CXI_RSA_GEN_KEY");      
          CryptoServerCXI.Key     rsaKey = cxi.findKey(attr);
              
              byte [] keyBlob = cxi.exportKey(rsaKey, CryptoServerCXI.KEY_TYPE_PRIVATE, aesKey);   

        

here i am trying with different overloading methods but still i am not able to get the actual key which i am storing.
can anybody please suggest is this the correct approach or what is going wrong in my case.

There are four different export levels, set using the KeyAttributes object's setExport(int level) method.

Export Denied (internal key, will not leave the HSM under any circumstances).
Backup Allowed (internal or external key, can be backed up using different tools).
Export Wrapped (internal or external key, can be exported wrapped using an additional key).
Export allow plain (don't do this).

The default exportability flag is "Backup Allowed" (level 2).  Since you did not set an export flag, the system will not provide the key to you because the key's export flag prevents it.  Levels 1, 3, and 4 have a CryptoServerCXI.FLAG_EXPORT final that you can use for the desired accessibility.  There's none for level 2, just don't bother calling the setExport(...) method of the key attributes before creating the key.
NOTE:  BEFORE CREATING THE KEY.  Once the key is created, you can not retroactively change the export policy.
(Rhetorical) But I'm really wondering why you think you need the key. The purpose of an HSM is to protect the keys.  If you are just going to suck them back out, why bother buying an HSM?
Ok, assuming you don't want to get the key itself, but you just want to refer to the key for later use.
The class CryptoServerCXI.KeyAttributes is used to set up the Name, Group and Specifier, as these are the three things which are used to differentiate between keys.  Instantiate a KeyAttributes, use its setters to set the name, group and spec, and then pass it as a param to findKey, which you did.  If the return value is not null, then you have a key handle, which is the reference to the key.
How can this fail?

Permissions -- you are using a user who is not a Cryptographic User (permission mask ending in 2)
Permissions -- your Cryptographic User is in the wrong CXI_GROUP (which would need to match 'test1' because that is the group name you are using for the key).

Note that a KeyHandle does NOT have or include any of the meta information about the key.  It's a handle, and that is all it is.
Your first extract generates an AES key, and your second tries to get a handle to the AES key and to an RSA key, but I don't know where you generated the RSA key.
It would be helpful for you to add the error numbers that you are getting from your attempts.  Telling us "it doesn't work" gets an answer back like "sorry to hear that".  Great social interaction but it doesn't solve your engineering problem.

It's not literally CryptoServerCXI.FLAG_EXPORT.  I don't have my work laptop, it being Saturday.  I /think/ it's .EXPORT_DENY, .EXPORT_ALLOW, and EXPORT_ALLOW_PLAIN, but you'll have to look them up.

thanks for your reply @rip.  my intention is to store the keys securely, and perfomr the crypto operations. meaning. i have PIV cards and will store those keys in Utimaco hsm. and while doing the credential issuance i need to give those keys so that my Applet team and they will put some data into that key. this is what my requirement, so could you please suggest what are the steps i need to perform there.

and can you please help me with what exactly i have to do after store the keys in the HSM in order to use.

There's example source for CXI in C++ and Java, JCE, PKCS11 and several other crypto systems in the distribution.  And Utimaco offers training, both self-paced and instructor led.  The problem I have is that what you think you want to do is so far removed from what the HSM is supposed to provide.  The questions you are asking are "wrong", by which I mean that the basic set of assumptions you have are out of sync with what an HSM is and what it does.

I keep rereading what you wrote, and it looks like you think that the HSM is some sort of key store for when the keys are at rest.  HSMs are designed to protect the keys.  If you are talking about "putting keys in" and then later "taking them out"... that's not what an HSM is for.
You send a request to the HSM with an operation to perform, a reference to the keys you want to use, and the input data.  If the operation, keys and data are correct, then what you get back is the result of the operation using the keys on the data.  It's "Sign this blob with the key called Harold".

Hey Rip, thanks again for your continued support, What is my requirement? I have to store the keys in HSM. then after how i can refer those keys is what my requirement is, but may be i am oversimplifying and conveying something like retrive the keys. No, thats not what i am saying just want to know i can i refer.

Hi rip.. thanks for your suggestions, Can you please help me with one thing. i have gone through the simulator Java example. i am able to store the keys and using AES algorithm, and for my PIV card, i want to store the keys with DES and 3DES algorithms. but i am not able to find any example. can you help me with this.

You'll get more out of SO if you learn the rules.  Post your work.  If you don't post your work, others can only assume or guess.  Since I don't know what you did, I can't tell you what to change to make it do the same thing for DES/3DES.  What did you try? Did it work? If not, how did it fail/what error message was returned?
